# Meteor Error executing Cordova commands: While running Cordova app for platform iOS with options --emulator:

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, meteor-helper

I'm kinda new to Meteor and Cordova. I am getting the error below when try to run 'meteor run ios android-device'. I did meteor update and reset but that did no fix. I try adding -- production but that I it's no solve.

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform iOS with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /Users/johndow/Projects/jackpot/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/run --emulator
   ENOENT, no such file or directory
   '/Users/johndow/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/31C952E8-7A5B-475F-B1F9-E15E73456946/system.log'
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

/Users/johndow/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4.zv5a90++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
            ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

Here's the 'run' directory it is referring to:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env node

/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
*/


var args = process.argv;
var Api = require('./Api');
var nopt = require('nopt');

// Handle help flag
if(['--help', '/?', '-h', 'help', '-help', '/help'].indexOf(process.argv[2]) >= 0) {
    require('./lib/run').help();
    process.exit(0);
}

// Parse arguments (includes build params as well)
var opts = nopt({
    'verbose' : Boolean,
    'silent' : Boolean,
    'debug': Boolean,
    'release': Boolean,
    'nobuild': Boolean,
    'archs': String,
    'list': Boolean,
    'device': Boolean,
    'emulator': Boolean,
    'target' : String,
    'codeSignIdentity': String,
    'codeSignResourceRules': String,
    'provisioningProfile': String,
    'buildConfig' : String,
    'noSign' : Boolean
}, {}, args);

// Make options compatible with PlatformApi build method spec
opts.argv = opts.argv.remain;

new Api().run(opts).done(function() {
        console.log('** RUN SUCCEEDED **');
    }, function (err) {
        var errorMessage = (err && err.stack) ? err.stack : err;
        console.error(errorMessage);
        process.exit(2);
    });
```

Comment: Hello there  , did you find a solution for this error ?

Comment: Install x code. Accept agreements.  Don't specify emulator. And go with "cordova run ios" this will launch default emulator then switch to desired emulator version in the tool bar under hardware. If you run into issues run ios rebuild command again. Let me know how it goes. Cheers.